# Isolated points of the split interval

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider the split interval $S(I)$: that's the product space $I\times 2$ endowed with the lexicographic order. If we take the Cantor space $2^\omega$, why $S(2^\omega)$ has countably many isolated points?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easiest if you think in terms of the middle-thirds Cantor set $C$. Let $L$ be the set of left endpoints of the open intervals deleted in the construction of $C$, and let $R$ be the set of right endpoints of those intervals. Show that the set of isolated points of $S(C)$ is

$$(L\times\{1\})\cup(R\times\{0\})\;.$$

For example, $x=\left\langle\frac13,1\right\rangle$ and $y=\left\langle\frac23,0\right\rangle$ are isolated, because $x$ is the immediate predecessor of $y$, $x$ has $\left\langle\frac13,0\right\rangle$ as immediate predecessor, and $y$ has $\left\langle\frac23,1\right\rangle$ as immediate successor.